# How to list agreement for a plan using paypal REST API

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I use the paypal REST API sdk in Java. I want to know, how to list all the agreement of a plan with the REST API ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no API avaiable yet for listing billing agreements under a plan.

The recommended practice is to insert/update the `agreement-id` and `plan-id` entry in your database when you operates on the recourse (create/update/reactive/suspend/cancel) for reconciliation